# Can I plant bulbs (e.g. tulips) under a lemon tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, bulbs, citrus, tulips

I've just been given some tulip bulbs, and pondering where to put them.  I have space near a lemon tree that I have just planted.

I have read that lemons have shallow roots, so you shouldn't plant things near them because they will compete for resources.  On the other hand, it seems to me that tulips will collect their nutrients from deeper in the soil, so this would not be a problem.

So can I plant bulbs near my lemon tree?

Answer (score 4):

Lemons need acid soil. Tulips prefer the soil slightly alkaline. If you still want to grow them here, Put 5" of good, slightly alkaline topsoil in a twelve inch deep pot. Then place the tulip bulbs right side up on the soil, and fill the pot the rest of the way up with the same soil. Then dig a hole and plant the whole thing level with the ground level. Then mulch the entire area. People do this all the time under conifers in my area.